# Group array items with eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following eloquent query:

```
$extras = EventExtra::select('id', 'category', 'name', 'price', 'description', 'company')->get();
```

It gets some data from me from my database.  What i want is for the returned data to be grouped twice, first by the category and then second by the company so that in the end i have something like this returned to the client:

```
    [
  {
    "name": "donation",
    "collection": [
        {
          "name": "sampleCompany1",
          "array": [
            {
              "name": "extra1",
              "description": "",
              "value": ""
            },
            {
              "name": "extra4",
              "description": "",
              "value": ""
            },
            {
              "name": "extra6",
              "description": "",
              "value": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
  },
{
  "name": "donation",
  "collection":  [
      {
        "name": "sampleCompany2",
        "array": [
          {
            "name": "extra2",
            "description": "",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "extra3",
            "description": "",
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}]
```

I just typed the above myself so it might not be valid object array but basically it shows what i want to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collection` to build your custom object. Something like this:

```
$return_data = Collect();
```

To add items in the collection with a property, you can use the `put` function.

```
$inner_data->put('name',$extras->name);
```

You can also add a collection within a collection.
To just push an existing collection in the collection, use `push` function

```
$inner_data->push($some_collection)
```

EDIT: Since you want a working example, see this below:

Lets say you want to create the following using collection:

```
{
    "name": "extra1"
    "description": "",
    "value": ""
}
```

You will do something like this:

```
$my_collection = Collect();
$my_collection->put('name','extra1');
$my_collection->put('description','');
$my_collection->put('value','');
```

Now you can add this collection to another collection where you don't need a key. So lets say now it looks like this:

```
[
    {
     "name": "extra1"
     "description": "",
     "value": ""
    },
    {
     "name": "extra4"
     "description": "",
     "value": ""
    }
]
```

You will now do:

```
$my_final_collection = Collect();
foreach($my_collections as $my_collection) {
    $my_final_collection->push($my_collection); // and so on in a loop
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but i am confused by your use of "return_data" first then "inner_data", i can't see a loop or assignment either.

Comment: I am not giving you the exact code for your problem. I gave you an idea of using Collection to build your custom object. This is not complete code.

Comment: Yes i understand that, but this "collection()" thing is new to me, i have never used or even seen it before, i checked the laravel docs for documentation and samples but that section has very little info.  It would really help me a lot if i could see a working sample from you please.

Comment: Thank you that really helped, facing another issue with grouping the data but i guess i'll just make another post for it. :):